# Handling parameters passed through react-router in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So, in react-router v4, my Route looks like this:

```
      <Route path="/suppliers/:id?" component={Suppliers} />
```

I'm passing an optional 'id' parameter to my Suppliers component. This is no problem.

For posterity, this is my Link: `<Link to="/suppliers/123">Place Order</Link>`

Then, in my component, I refer to the parameter as such:
        `<p>{this.props.match.params.id}</p>`

This works, but my linter gives me the following error: `[eslint] 'match' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)`

For this reason, I've defined the propTypes as such:

```
Suppliers.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
    }).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

But it feels like I'm writing more boilerplate code than I probably require. My question is, Is there a better way to define my propTypes in my component so as to avoid the linter error? Also, this solution seems unsustainable if, for instance, the props.match property changes it will break. Or am I doing this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can set default value for match prop and not make it `isRequired`. This way if the shape changes you just get a warning not an error. Or you can just ignore the eslint error.

Comment: But then I'd have to define a default value for match, and that's opening a whole new bag of worms...

Comment: You can give match a default value of an empty object. I don't think its gonna be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is okay but you can also define the proptypes as object.

```
match: PropTypes.object.isRequired
```

If one day you need other props such `match, location, history`. you can define it this way.

```
Suppliers.propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
```

Comment: This gives me the error: `[eslint] Prop type \`object\` is forbidden (react/forbid-prop-types)`

Comment: (the same happens for 'any')

Comment: @DrSatan1 Sorry, I think they want you to describe the proptypes. If you don't want, you can disable it. Ref: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md

Comment: @DrSatan1 this is the same as your problem https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/904

Answer (score 0):

In order to cover these cases regarding match (and history) to please linters, you can declare your prop-types like so:

```js
     Suppliers.propTypes = {
      match: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
      }).isRequired,
    };
```

This was the solution that worked best for us in our project.